# Openssl: Generate CSR for private key read from stdin

Tags: windows, openssl

I am tring to get openssl to generate a CSR for an existing private key using the windows binary of OpenSSL.

Normally the command line for this would be:

`openssl.exe req -new -sha256 -out test.csr -key privkey.pem`

However for security reasons I'd like to provide the key via standard input so I don't need to store the private key file on disk.

There was a [similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/407874/openssl-csr-generation-with-subject-key-from-stdin) with a solution specific to Linux, however I am using Windows so that cannot be applied.

Comment: The private key file isn't stored anywhere?  How do you use it?

Comment: It is only present in memory during runtime of my program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike the Linux build the Windows build of openssl supports `-` to tell the application to read from stdin.

```
openssl.exe req -new -sha256 -out test.csr -key -
```

Another option would be to use a RAM drive to store the key file temporarily.